# Why is _this.state.searchAddress() not a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am attempting a search query in react-native using axios however, when I attempt to read it to console I get this error:

> _this.state.searchAddress is not a function.(In'`this.state.searchAddress()','_this.state.searchAddress'
>   is "data"

I am learning react-native coming from C++ so I do not completely understand these errors. The error is thrown on `addressSearch`.

```js
class MainScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    searchAddress: "",
    addressData: {}
  };

  addressSearch = () => {
    console.log(this.state.searchAddress);
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    const addyZip = this.state.searchAddress();

    const query =
      "https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/voterinfo?address= " +
      addyZip +
      "&electionId=6000&key=";

    axios.get(query).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <SearchHeader
          value={this.state.searchAddress}
          onChangeText={searchAddress => this.setState({ searchAddress })}
          addressSearch={this.addressSearch}
        />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default MainScreen;
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable `this.state.searchAddress` is a string, which you set initially to `""`, when you set the initial state. You are attempting to call a string as a function, but a string is not a function.

You probably meant:

```
const addyZip = this.state.searchAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

basically in addressSearch function you need to change

const addyZip = this.state.searchAddress();

to

const addyZip = this.state.searchAddress;

since this.state.searchAddress is a string not a function.